# gitlab with two ssh keys not connecting (config updated)

Tags: git, macos, ssh, gitlab

I have a gitlab account on my mac which has the neccessary ssh key on it for my work account. I am trying to set up gitlab for all my personal projects. I have created a personal account on gitlab and created a ssh key.

I have edited the config file in ~/.shh/ to look like this

```
Host markgameforeverything.gitlab.com
    HostName gitlab.com
    User git
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/personal.pub

Host markbreadcreative.gitlab.com
    HostName gitlab.com
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

however I am not able to

```
git pull
```

as I get this error

```
GitLab: The project you were looking for could not be found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists
```

if I type

```
ssh -T git@gitlab.com
```

I get

```
Welcome to GitLab, *my work account welcome*!
```

(the wrong account)
Can anyone suggest any further steps I may take or see an error in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check how does your `.git/config` look like. I guess you don't have there `url` starting with `markbreadcreative.` and `markgameforeverything.` prefixes.

To get your setup working, you need to modify the lines in your repo from

```
url = git@gitlab.com:whatever.git
```

to

```
url = git@markbreadcreative.gitlab.com:whatever.git
url = git@markgameforeverything.gitlab.com:whatever.git
```

respectively depending on which account you want to use. You can check your configuration using:

```
ssh -T git@markbreadcreative.gitlab.com
ssh -T git@markgameforeverything.gitlab.com
```

(should return different results). If not, post a verbose log from such commands (`ssh -vvvT git@markgameforeverything.gitlab.com`).

Comment: sorry how do you open  .git/config

Comment: if I do ssh -T git@markbreadcreative.gitlab.com I get hello mark

Comment: In your favourite text editor using *Open* menu, for example.

Comment: I have the exact same problem, but I am unable to check `ssh -T git@<personal-account>.gitlab.com` as it says "couldn't resolve hostname".

Comment: @aalaap because you do not have the ssh properly configured in `~/.ssh/config`.

Comment: @Jakuje yes, i identified the problem and fixed it! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53494350/how-can-i-connect-to-gitlab-with-two-different-ssh-users