# How can I connect to GitLab with two different ssh users?

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I have two GitLab accounts - one for my personal projects and one for work - and both of them have SSH keys generated and added. There is an `id_rsa` for the work account (because that's what I created first) and an `id_rsa_personal` for the personal one. My `~/ssh/config` is as follows:

```
Host gitlab-personal
    Preferredauthentications publickey
    User personalusername
    HostName gitlab.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_personal
Host gitlab-work
    Preferredauthentications publickey
    User workusername
    HostName gitlab.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Yet, when I run `ssh -vvvT git@personalusername.gitlab.com`, I get the following:

```
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/personalusername/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "personalusername.gitlab.com" port 22
ssh: Could not resolve hostname personalusername.gitlab.com: Name or service not known
```

The fourth line (`Applying options for *`) seems to indicate that `ssh` has ignored both of my config settings and picked up the defaults, which is to use `id_rsa`. Since that is my work account, I am unable to clone my personal repositories, resulting in the following error:

```
git clone git@gitlab.com:personalusername/personalproject.git personalprojecttest
Cloning into 'personalprojecttest'...
GitLab: The project you were looking for could not be found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

There is a similar question with an answer ([gitlab with two ssh keys not connecting (config updated)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35297959/gitlab-with-two-ssh-keys-not-connecting-config-updated)), but that talks about specifying the username in Git config. My problem is that I do not have or want a global Git config as I am doing both personal as well as work work on the same machine. I prefer to have a local Git config (in ./.git/config), however, this folder doesn't exist yet, so I have no local Git config.

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As usual, I fixed the issue myself moments after writing up this question. I modified my `~/ssh/config` file with this:

```
Host gitlab.com
    Preferredauthentications publickey
    User personalusername@personalemailaddress.com
    HostName gitlab.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_personal
Host gitlab.com
    Preferredauthentications publickey
    User workusername@workemailaddress.com
    HostName gitlab.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I quite simply changed the `User personalusername` to use the email address instead of the username. I was able to clone my personal projects successfully after this.

Also the `ssh -vvvT git@personalusername.gitlab.com` command was wrong. The correct one is just `ssh -vvvT git@gitlab.com`, the output of which had mentions of both keys. This is what led me to give the `git clone` command another shot, just to check.

Comment: Isn't it suposed to be `~/.ssh/config`?

Answer (score 3):

~/.ssh/config:

```
Host gitlab-personal
    User git
    HostName gitlab.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_personal
    Preferredauthentications publickey

Host gitlab-work
    User git
    HostName gitlab.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    Preferredauthentications publickey
```

Then try `ssh -vvvT gitlab-personal`, `ssh -vvvT gitlab-work`.

Run

```
git clone gitlab-personal:personalusername/personalproject.git
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_personal`? Booth keys should be added to ssh-agent.

Comment: I didn't but I don't think that is the problem. It is aware of both keys, but it just isn't able to figure out which key to use for which user.

Comment: Not an expert, but some time ago, as i remember, this was main solution for me to set up multiple identities.

Comment: that was the missing piece for me. I added `ssh-add ~/.ssh/something` and now I can ssh with no problems.